# Using BigQuery in Google Sheets, how do I give another user permission to press 'refresh'?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, google-bigquery

I have BigQuery permissions, and Google Sheets, under a company owned Google account.

I have made a spreadsheet for a colleague, the data for which is there via a BigQuery data connection, which creates a sheet in the spreadsheet with the results of that query.

There's a button at the bottom left that tells you how many rows were returned, what time it was run, and has a 'REFRESH' button on it.

I can press the refresh button and it refreshes the data by running the query again. My colleague gets an error when they do.

What (presumably BigQuery) permission do they requirement in order to be able to press the 'REFRESH' button and have it work?

Comment: There is no script - there is a BigQuery data insertion as per this: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some tests regarding your scenario, I added the "BigQuery Data Viewer" and "BigQuery User" roles to my test user to not get the "Excecution Error" message while pressing the "REFRESH" button. For more information regarding BigQuery roles, please review the [following document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles).

Hope it helps.

Comment: as a understand what you're saying is basically that you need to give specific BigQuery permissions to the user pressing the Refresh button, isn't it?

Comment: That's right. The user need to have permissions too