# BigQuery Connected Sheets - Required user permissions?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a view that is connected to a google sheet via connected sheets.

I'm trying to let a user refresh the data by giving them access in GCP.

I've tried giving access at the project, dataset and view levels. But every time they get the error: "Query failed, no access to the connected BigQuery table"

I'm giving the role of bigquery.user and bigquery.dataviewer.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Please, make sure if the user you wish to give access to the BigQuery data in Google Sheets has:

- An Enterprise Plus or G Suite Enterprise for Education account
- Access to BigQuery
- A project with billing setup in BigQuery
- A BigQuery Job Creator role on the selected billing project
- BigQuery Data Viewer role on the datasets containing the selected table

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9703001?hl=en&ref_topic=9699960):

> If you share a sheet with someone who doesn't meet the criteria
> above, they'll be able to see analysis created with Connected Sheets
> and perform regular Sheets operations, but they won't be able to
> refresh it or create their own connected sheet.

Additionally, have a look for the another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480854/using-bigquery-in-google-sheets-how-do-i-give-another-user-permission-to-press) and [Using Connected Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets#access_control) documentation.

Comment: Adding Job Creator worked for me